# How do I use multiple laptops as external display over network?

Tags: wireless, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, vnc

I have a relatively powerful computer (8gb ram, 64bit, quad core) and I can easily drive three monitors, my tv over hdmi, my 17 inch hd internal laptop display, and an external hd display. I have (literally) 8 laptops, and only one vga port on my main one, and my tv is impossible to use much of the time. I really like the idea of using my wireless (all of my computers have it) to link them all and display all six of my desktops on my computer at once, or just have a 6 monitor extended desktop. How would I achieve this? I don't just want them to share my cursor, I want to be able to drag windows between them, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basic way**.
If `sshd` is installed on your laptops you can connect with them with `ssh -X` from the central one. Once you have done you can run each graphic program and the graphical output will be redirected to your main one.

**More complex one**.
With [**NoMachine**](https://www.nomachine.com/) e.g., server and client, you can connect to a remote computer as if you where connected directly. It's a remote desktop as many other. So from your central computer you can connect to all your laptop, maybe one for desktop.

To exchange windows from one computer to another... I suppose for this you need to create a something like a grid with all cloned machine (probably you can realize with virtual machines...). I see it a little bit more challenging.

Comment: I feel that ubuntu should include some native method of making it a slave monitor. I'll see if I can figure out what you said and how to do it, then report back if it works. Thanks!